# Having problems to loop through the contents of the cupcakesTest folder. I need to use the for loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

`cupcakesTest` is a folder which contains 2 markdown files. (Descriptions of cupcakes).
Its located in the project folder.

```html
---
layout: post
title: Muffins
---
<h1>Our Cupcakessssss</h1>

<div class="cupcakes">

  {{ site.cupcakesTest }}

  {% for cupcake in site.cupcakesTest %}
    <div class="cupcake">
      <div class="image"><img src="{{ cupcake.image_path }}"/></div>
      <h2>{{ cupcake.type }}</h2>
    </div>    
  {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `site.cupcakesTest` to be valid:

- the "directory" should start with an underscore: (`_cupcakesTest/`)
- and added as a *collection* in your `_config.yml`

  ```yaml
  # _config.yml

  collections:
    - cupcakesTest
  ```